# PSQL Where clause with logical operators "AND" "OR" "NOT"

Tags: postgresql, analytics, logical-operators

Here is my problem in a basket analysis query a customer can choose his basket and call a search query like this

```
select ti.* from transaction t join transaction_items ti on ti.unique_id = t.unique_id where ti.display_description  'ROMA TOMATO' AND 'BANANA' AND ('JALAPENO' OR 'ONION WHITE' AND ('SALSA' OR 'GUACAMOLE')),
        'VITAMINS' AND 'PRODUCE' OR ('POTATO' AND 'SHRIMP') AND NOT ('MEAT' OR 'FISH' OR 'PIE')
```

In the above query, two different baskets are searched. By ',' we can separate the baskets.
As result we have to provide data group by basket.
sales for basket one `'ROMA TOMATO' AND 'BANANA' AND ('JALAPENO' OR 'ONION WHITE' AND ('SALSA' OR 'GUACAMOLE'))`
And for basket two `'VITAMINS' AND 'PRODUCE' OR ('POTATO' AND 'SHRIMP') AND NOT 'MEAT' OR 'FISH' OR 'PIE'`

sample data of transaction_item table

```
amt     qty  display_description     unique_id 
2.470   1   ROMA TOMATO "2704-7075-12-201111"
2.470   1   BANANA  "2704-7075-12-201111"
2.190   1   JALAPENO    "2704-7075-12-201111"
2.190   1   ONION   "2704-7075-12-201111"
2.190   1   SALSA   "2704-7075-12-201111"
0.880   1   GUACAMOLE   "2704-7075-12-201111"
2.860   4840    VITAMINS    "2704-7075-12-201111"
1.580   2   PRODUCE "2704-7075-12-201111"
3.560   1550    POTATO  "2704-7075-12-201111"
0.990   1   SHRIMP  "2704-7075-12-201111"
0.340   1   MEAT    "2704-7075-12-201111"
0.340   1   MEAT    "2704-7075-12-201111"
0.330   1   FISH    "2704-7075-12-201111"
0.330   1   FISH    "2704-7075-12-201111"
0.330   1   PIE "2704-7075-12-201111"
0.330   1   ABC "2704-7075-12-201111"
0.330   1   ABC "2704-7075-12-201111"
0.330   1   ABC "2704-7075-12-201111"
0.330   1   XYZ "2704-7075-12-201111"
0.990   1   XYZ "2704-7075-12-201111"
0.500   1   XYZ "2704-7075-12-201111"
0.500   1   XYZ "2704-7075-12-201111"
2.470   1   ROMA TOMATO "2704-7075-12-201112"
2.470   1   BANANA  "2704-7075-12-201112"
2.190   1   JALAPENO    "2704-7075-12-201112"
2.190   1   ONION   "2704-7075-12-201112"
2.190   1   SALSA   "2704-7075-12-201112"
0.880   1   GUACAMOLE   "2704-7075-12-201112"
2.860   4840    VITAMINS    "2704-7075-12-201112"
1.580   2   PRODUCE "2704-7075-12-201112"
3.560   1550    POTATO  "2704-7075-12-201112"
0.990   1   SHRIMP  "2704-7075-12-201112"
0.330   1   ABC "2704-7075-12-201112"
0.330   1   ABC "2704-7075-12-201112"
0.330   1   ABC "2704-7075-12-201112"
0.330   1   XYZ "2704-7075-12-201112"
0.990   1   XYZ "2704-7075-12-201112"
0.500   1   XYZ "2704-7075-12-201112"
0.500   1   XYZ "2704-7075-12-201112"
```

Comment: How do you expect a single column to contain the value `ROMA TOMATO` **and** `BANANA` at the same time?

Comment: Worst possible datamodel that creates a ton of problems. Don't even bother to try to fix these problems, fix the real problem: Your datamodel.

Comment: I have modified my question can you revisit it once.
transaction_item have multiple rows for a single transaction_id

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables.

Comment: Provided sample data